# Why can't to-infinitive be used as subject in "Not to learn French is my biggest regret."?

Tags: infinitives, gerund-vs-infinitive

E.g. 1 "Not learning French is my biggest regret."

E.g. 2 "Not to learn French is my biggest regret."

I know that e.g. 1 is correct and e.g. 2 is wrong, but what is the grammar rule making e.g. 2 incorrect?

(At first I thought the rule was that you shouldn't use to-infinitive as the subject, but then I realized it couldn't be the rule as to-infinitive is sometimes used as the subject, as in "To tell the truth is always right.")

Comment: I would say 'Not _having done_ something is my regret', and use 'Not to do it' when speaking of future intentions.

Answer (score 2):

> Re:

- *Not learning French is my biggest regret.*

but not

- **Not to learn French is my biggest regret.*

Really, the negative is just a distraction. You can't say

- **To learn French is my biggest regret*

either.

The reason is simply that the complex predicate adjective *be one's biggest regret* does not allow an infinitive subject complement.  If if did, it might be extraposed, but, no:

- **It is my biggest regret (not) to learn French*

Comment: Does the perfect make some of these more acceptable? Maybe it’s just semantic satiety (well, syntactic satiety) but even though I find *My biggest regret was to have never learned French* unremarkable, I find most similar formulations with *not* to be clumsy or ambiguous or just plain off: *My biggest regret was (not to have / to not have / to have not) learned French.*  By ambiguous, I mean preliminary uncertainty about whether it’s about to turn into something like *My biggest regret was not to have started but to have stopped,* which seems to parse ok to me.

Answer (score 1):

At its most basic without a full lecture:

Gerunds are used when actions are real, fixed, or completed. "I enjoy cooking."

Infinitives are used when actions are unreal, abstract, or future: "He wants to swim."

...........but there are loads of exceptions!