# "Not to watch" vs "Not to have watched" as subject of a sentence

Tags: negation, infinitives, subjects, gerund-vs-infinitive

E.g. 1 **Not to watch** Kobe Bryant's matches when he was alive is my biggest regret.

£.g. 2 **Not to have watched** Kobe Bryant's matches when he was alive is my biggest regret.

Am I right that e.g. 1 is not grammatical whereas e.g. 2 is grammatical? If yes, why is it so?

Comment: Not **having watched** Kobe Bryant's matches when he was alive is my biggest regret.

Comment: You already asked essentially the same thing as [Why can't to-infinitive be used as subject in “Not to learn French is my biggest regret.”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/538482/why-cant-to-infinitive-be-used-as-subject-in-not-to-learn-french-is-my-biggest)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd go so far as to say it's a duplicate.

Comment: @JasonBassford: I suspect the exact text of the closevote reason ("Does this answer your question?") is actually just typical "British" understatement. (Meaning ***This is a duplicate!*** :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers As I'm sure you know, the old text used to be more definite. A recent close-vote revamp changed it to the qualified form.

Comment: I consider it a duplicate as well.